# How to install or enable mysqlnd in CentOS 6.6 [DirectAdmin]

Tags: centos6, mysqlnd, directadmin

How to install or enable **mysqlnd** in CentOS 6.6 and php 5.5 ?

directadmin installed in server and **yum commands** not working.

i use directAdmin CustomBuild like this.

```
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock \
```

but after **./build php n** nothing happend.

please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give a try with following commands.

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
mkdir -p custom/ap2
cp -fp configure/ap2/configure.php5 custom/ap2/configure.php5

Make changes to custom/ap2/configure.php5
Add the following lines

--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock \

Then rebuild PHP via custombuild

./build php n
```